# Grails run server

Tags: grails

I sucessfully managed to complete with my Grail's new website and now i want to run it on my machine to acess it everywhere. I would like to know what is the best approach to do that, i'm a bit noob in what concerns servers and connections. Any help would be aprecciated.

Jm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need persistent storage in your app (e.g. end users uploading pictures, etc), you can use Cloud Foundry. It's free for now and makes deployment very easy.

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/04/12/one-step-deployment-with-grails-and-cloud-foundry/

I've been using is via STS and it works really well. There's just one really annoying thing and that's the fact that STS ends up doing a build war with every change.

There's a cloud foundry plugin that gives you command line deployment.

http://www.grails.org/plugin/cloud-foundry

Or there's a Cloud Foundry UI plugin that "provides a simple monitoring UI for your applications deployed to Cloud Foundry. It uses the same API as the Cloud Foundry plugin but is more convenient since runs in a web browser."

http://www.grails.org/plugin/cloud-foundry-ui

Answer (score 2):

You need a Java servlet container. The quickest and easiest approach is probably to use Jetty on a Linux system -- most will allow you to install it directly. This allows you run a deployed system from a "war" file. Basically, you would do something like:

```
grails war
```

To build the war file, and then copy that (it'll be created in the target directory, with a name based on your application name and version) to the webapps directory for Jetty. On my (Ubuntu) system, that's `/var/lib/jetty/webapps/`. If you name it `root.war`, it will serve URLs from the root of the server configuration (typically on port 8080), so `http://myhost.mydomain:8080/` will be passed to your Grails application. You'll need to restart Jetty to pick up the new root.war file, e.g., `sudo /etc/init.d/jetty restart`

Jetty is not the most flexible or powerful servlet container, but it is probably the quickest way to get something up and running, and you can explore more powerful alternatives (Tomcat being an obvious one) as you have time.

Comment: I've never used Jetty, but Tomcat is pretty simple.

Comment: **FYI**:Grails should be installed in server machine..!!

Comment: Grails doesn't actually need to be installed on the server -- at least, we don't install it on our production servers and the site deploys and runs just fine. "grails war" builds a war file that contains enough Groovy and Grails runtime stuff to make everything work